# Angle measurement of cube vertices

Tags: trigonometry

How was the angle 35.264 degrees in the following image gotten?

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia_isometric_cube_3.jpg

I know it involves some sort of trigonometry. I also know the blue arrow passes through opposite corners of the cube.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out myself visually and atan(sin(45)) is the answer I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+a^2+a^2}}$

Answer (score 2):

The main diagonal of a cube of side $a$ is $D=\sqrt{a^2+a^2+a^2}=a\sqrt 3$. The diagonal of the basis of the cube is $d=\sqrt{a^2+a^2}=a \sqrt 2$. So the angle $\theta$ between them is such that:$\cos \theta=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3}$, and 
$ \arccos (\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 3})$ is your angle ([see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%28%5Csqrt%282%29%2F%5Csqrt%283%29%29)).

Answer (score 1):

From direction cosines
$$ \cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta +\cos^2 \gamma = 1 $$
When the three sides are equal, the sides are equally inclined to the largest side of cube.

$$ 3 \cos^2 A = 1 $$

Its solution is 35.264  deg

Comment: I am plugging the angle into your second formula and am getting 2 instead of 1. In code instead of latex:

(cos(35.264))^2 * 3

Comment: I am sorry,please draw a diagram of full cube with both directions. It was hint at the max inclination situation. The angle in the picture has a cosine = adj side / hypotenuse = $ \sqrt 2$/$ \sqrt 3$.